# How to get the json message from url using xamarin cross platform development?

Tags: cross-platform, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

How to get the json data from url using xamarin cross platform development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using xamarin to retrieve JSON message from URl and show in table view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606824/using-xamarin-to-retrieve-json-message-from-url-and-show-in-table-view)

Comment: You just asked this same question a few hours ago.  Please do not post duplicates.

Comment: @Jason sorry just now only i saw that. I forgot that because no one answered that question. that's y only.

Comment: @Jason could you know the answer for this

Comment: You accepted the answer in your other question.  What do you still need help with?

Comment: sorry, unfortunately by mouse clicking it was accepted. still i didn't get proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
private const string Url = "http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf={0}";
public async Task<List<RootObject>> GetResult(string SearchString)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(Url, SearchString));
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json.ToString());
    }
    catch (System.Exception exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

using `HttpClient` call url and `getStrinAsyncc` to get string from the url. using `DeserializeObject` to convert the string into json format.
For refer more [click here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27037/how-to-get-a-json-data-from-url-and-shown-in-mobile-app#latest) to see complete program in xamarin