# Cannot print the json message in listview using xamarin cross platform

Tags: json, listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, cross-platform

Using a xamarin cross platform development to i want print a json message from url and print in listview. I write code without error but with some mistakes. I will not work. For just a verfication output only i print the button in the output screen. I will shown but the listview was not print. Please recorrect my code.

```
    static ListView listview;
    static Button button;
    public MainPage()
    {
        listview = new ListView() { RowHeight = 40 };
        button = new Button() { Text = "search Again" };
        var stack = new StackLayout()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = { button, listview },
        };
        this.Content = stack;
        GetData();
    }
     async static void GetData()
    {
        WeatherReport res = new WeatherReport();
        try
        {
            string contents;
            string Url = String.Format("http://23.253.66.248:8080/icc/api/venue/search/?                lat=39.540544&lon=-104.866115&appkey=123Chesse&restName=MyMacChennai&organization=MyMacChennai");
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            contents = await hc.GetStringAsync(Url);
            res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherReport>(contents);
            listview.ItemsSource = res.list;
        }
        catch (System.Exception sysExc)
        {
            // Do something to log this error.
            throw;
        }
    }
 public class WeatherReport
 {
    public WeatherReport()
    {
        list = new List<WeatherReport>();
    }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cod")]
    public string cod { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "message")]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cnt")]
    public int cnt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "list")]
    public List<WeatherReport> list { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you verified your data is being populated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use `async void` except for eventhandlers, it is bad practice. Second, `GetData()` is an asynchronous method, however you are calling it synchronously in a constructor. I would advise redesigning this a bit so that it is async all the way through. You may be having issues since you are waiting for the code to finish before continuing on. Everything else in the code *appears* ok.

Here are some additional resources that might help with async/await.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx, 
[async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)